# How to manually serve files on Parse.com?

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform

I've deployed a single-page app using a frontend framework to my Parse Hosting.

However, there's a huge issue in there: sub-paths get routed to the `/public` folder, and there's only an `index.html` and a bunch of assets in there.

I've tried numerous options on serving that static index file through all other routes, by using `Express` or `HTTP` in `cloud/main.js`, but it seems Parse runs a custom subset of Node modules. They've **erased** all filesystem methods. There's no `sendFile()` on Express API, no `readFile()`on fs module...

What can I do to achieve that?? I just need all paths not in the `public` folder to serve the same thing: my `index.html` file.

---

What I've already tried:

**Read the file and serve it:**

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('../public/index.html', 'utf8' , function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

**Serve it as an Express Middleware (probably the most efficient way):**

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('../public/index.html');
});
```

**Serve it as a catch-all route:**

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('../public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Also trying to do this, seems like there has to be a way.