# How to serve gzipped content on Parse.com?

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, gzip

It seems the guys on [Parse.com don't want to speed up our hosted content](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/388232707995327/) by enabling gzip in their Hosting service.

It seems it's also not possible to simply [read files and serve them through Parse's Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551995/how-to-manually-serve-files-on-parse-com).

Given these horrid limitations, is it possible to still serve gzipped content in some way? I can add a gzip step in my build process but I have no idea how to manually serve those to enabled browsers.

> *My build went from 1.5MB to 360KB when gzipped. That's a reduction of more than 4x! That's very important for mobile users (one of the Parse targets, right?)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expressjs/compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) middleware

> ```
> var compression = require('compression')
> var express = require('express')  
> var app = express()
> // compress all requests
> app.use(compression())
> ```

Comment: that module is yet not available on parse.com :(