# Send a static file for a specifed URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I am currently using parse to deploy my web app. I am using Express to route the url to the appropriate content.

Currently I trying to serve index.html for the following url;

```
mystackoverflowapp.parseapp.com/hi
```

In my cloud code I have the following request handler

```
app.get('/hi', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

According to the parse documentation the default directory is the public directory. Unfortunately this request handler does not work. When I go to my stackoverflow.parseapp.com I get a 500 error, "Internal Server Error".

I am following the same directory structure as outlined in the documentation and have tried having the index.html file in every directory.

If I try

```
res.send('This works!')
```

for the same route I get the expected response,

```
"This works!".
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Also, what's the best way to get better debugging on this? A 500 error doesn't really reveal too much.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a wrong path. To look at errors try this:

```
  res.sendFile('index.html', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log('File sent!');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Tried adding the error logs and viewed them by using parse logs. Is there a more legible way to view the logs? Maybe even have a live update of the logs as the request gets handled?

Answer (score 1):

From http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile:

> Unless the root option is set in the options object, path must be an
>   absolute path of the file.

Update 1: I tried this:

```
app.get('/test', function(req,res) {
    try {
        res.sendFile('test.html');
    } catch (err) {
        res.send('ERROR ' + err);
    }
});
```

It produces:

> ERROR TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sendFile'

I then stumbled across this: [How to manually serve files on Parse.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551995/how-to-manually-serve-files-on-parse-com). The relevant quote:

> ...it seems Parse runs a custom subset of Node modules. They've **erased**
>   all filesystem methods. There's no sendFile() on Express API, no
>   readFile() on fs module...

Update 2:

Parse sets up a static file handler for your app, so try this:

```
app.get('/hi', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/index.html');
});
```

Comment: According to parse; https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#hosting-static-content the default directory is always set to public/

Comment: Tried to use __dirname but get the following error;

ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined

Comment: The redirect works but it would get rid of the URL in the address bar