# Alternatives to res.sendFile?

Tags: express, parse-platform

Is there an alternative to res.sendFile. It doesn't seem to be supported by parse.

https://parse.com/questions/is-there-an-alternative-to-expresss-ressendfile

What I am trying to accomplish is serve a specific file for a URL;

Have

```
example.com/servemesomefile
```

serve

```
somefile.html
```

Answer (score 0):

See my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709789/send-a-static-file-for-a-specifed-url/32709966#32709966) to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709789/send-a-static-file-for-a-specifed-url/). You can likely get the behavior your desire via a redirect response (assuming the file you want to send is in the `public` directory).

Comment: The redirect would work but it would get refresh the url in the address bar